# Can I detect a leftclick from mouse? Or Ctrl+Right Click?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to detect if a user pressed the left mouse button or right button + ctrl key, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I know do just detect a click, I could use

```
<li onClick=\"dosomething()\">
```

Is there a function to do

```
<li onLeftClick=\"dosomething()\"> ?
```

Comment: No, I mean left click. By default onClick ... is equivalent to right click. So I want to filter out a leftClick action ...

Comment: When you clicked 'add comment' which mouse button did you use?

Comment: @frames: Are you left-handed? `onclick` by default detects the **primary** mouse button, which is on the *left* for right-handed configuration (most common), and *right* for left-handed configuration. Note also that some browsers will not pass the context click (not-primary button) to the webpage.

Comment: Piskvor, I am right handed. Dampe ... sorry, you were right. I was just being foolish there! The reason I want the "right" click functionality, is that, I am currently doing something when the user clicks the "left" click, however I wanted to do something else as well, which I thought would be possible if I asked them to use their 'other' button ...

Comment: Which it is, so long as you ask for the right one. ;)

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery one could do something like

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    if (e.button == 0) {
        // was the left button
        alert('clicked'); 
    }
});
```

And with normal javascript there should be some kind of event variable accessible in an onClick function

Perhaps this'll also help yet I don't know if its still accurate

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/leftvsri.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `button` property of the event.

What you are definitely not going to like is that different browsers return different values: check out the documentation for [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.button) and [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533544%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). So you will also need to do a browser detect of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking on the wrong side of things. PHP is server-side, meaning it runs on the servers as opposed to the people visiting your site. When someone visits your site, the visitor (a `client`) sends the server computer a request for a page. The server receives that request and sends the client the information. When a client clicks his/her mouse, though, nothing is (by default) sent to the server.

The solution depends on what you need to do. If you need PHP scripts to run when you click something, look into sending asynchronous requests through AJAX. You can put your AJAX calls into the dosomething() function. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro1.html is a good place to start. If you're familiar with jQuery, though, it's a very simple function call: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I don't see a reference to php or ajax in his question. His example is javascript and the question is tagged javascript. Not sure why you think he's looking on the wrong side...

Comment: It was retagged ): It had PHP before.